# Why am I getting error during post url using angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api, google-api

ERROR on zone.js:2863 POST

Here is the URL

https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=AIzaSyCcMcGPiHTG7D9JUYTzpmmUPY-HsRbyl7E 400.

```
auth.services.ts file:

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthResponce } from './auth-inter-face/auth-responce';
import { config } from './config';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }


  signup(email:any,password:any){
     return this.http.post<AuthResponce>('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key='+ config.API_KEY,{
      email:email,
      password:password,
      returnSecureToken:true

    })
  }
}
```

[image]